# Every Magento Module SQL install script don't run anymore

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.5

I have a weird mistake, I'm working on Magento (1.5.1) but since I don't know when, installation scripts of modules doesn't work anymore, Magento seems not running SQL folders, for every kind of module.  I tried to make a basic external php script using PDO and the same connection setting (host, dbname, loggin, pwd) and that works so I guess it's not a SQL permission problem. I'm totally disappointed.

(sorry for that bad English... of course I'm French)

Have a nice day !

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your scripts have already been executed? Have a look into you core_resources table.

To execute an install script again, you need to have the previous version number in DB: if your script is update-0.0.1-0.0.2, you should have version and data_version to 0.0.1 in order to execute it.
If you want to install it, you shouldn't have any matching row in DB.

---

edit:
You'll also have to clear your cache, of course

PS: your English is fine, at least for an other French :)

Comment: you may try removing an entry from the core_resource table and clear your cache.

Comment: That's what I'm saying on my answer, Sulabh... But +1 for clearing the cache

Comment: Yes indeed, modules are listed in the core_ressource table but nothing is created no INSERT, no CREATE TABLE, have you any tips to try to debug an installation script ? 'cause He doesn't send me error message back.
And by the way (thank you)

Comment: Are you sure about your core_resource table? As I said, if you want to execute **-upadte-0.0.1-0.0.2.php, you must have the corresponding row's versions number equals "0.0.1" (correspondence is based on resource_code)

Comment: To test if the install script is played, you can use a Mage::log

Comment: In core_resource table : 

code:amstockstatus_setup,    
version:3.0.1,  
data_version:3.0.1,  

My files name: mysql4-install-1.0.0.php & mysql4-upgrade-1.0.10-2.0.0.php But I already install them on my local on Mage 1.6.0 and it works...

Comment: Then it's normal! It's a bit weird that you have version 3 in you DB... Anyway, if you want to execute mysql4-upgrade-1.0.10-2.0.0.php, you have to update your DB so the version match '1.0.10'

Comment: I have try to run installation code inside of an external script using that:
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    $installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
    $installer->startSetup(); And that works

Comment: what's your umask for here? All your directories rights should already be OK :s If it's neither the cache not the resources, I've no ideas, sorry

Comment: I don't really know about the umask using, it's was in a working snippet... Thank you for all you help Haltabush. I will keep installing module in this way.